# Pass range of files to stdin in Python

Tags: python, loops, terminal, command, stdin

I have a list of files in the same directory that are systematically named, eg. `'test01.ext','test02.ext','test03.ext'...'test99.ext'`. I want to, in Python, pass a certain range of these files to a loop. However, I want to be able to determine which files I want to loop in a command line, eg. `'test45.ext'` to `'test62.ext'`. How would I do this?

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
for fname in sys.stdin :
   Some_loop(fname)
```

How would I choose (without manually entering all files from eg. 45 to 62) a range of files when prompted?
Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a script. If it is only for one type of file name, the you can hardcore the file name, and input the range of numbers instead.

Comment: Yes, that is a better solution (see below) - I didn't know before how to handle looping through 00001...99999 in a filename. Thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: Start by defining your interface. What exactly do you want to type on the command line, and exactly which files should be opened as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files = sys.stdin.splitlines()
for n in range(start,end):
  fname = 'test%02d.ext' % (n,)
  if fname in files:
    some_loop(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice the list of files:

```
>>> a =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a[4:6]
[5, 6]
```

You might have to `.split('\n')` your file list beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, fast answer, but two questions: (1) I know the range of numbers, but how do I pass this to stdin in a terminal? and (2) I actually have a lot more than 100 files, so how would I handle the zeros in front? Eg. for a range 44 to 290, ie. text00044.ext to text00290.ext?